# input type radio-button has the wrong clicked value in IE after pressing the back button

Tags: javascript, radio-button, browser-history, checked, inspector

***It appears that there is something wrong with the way my page is created, which is causing the radio buttons to display one value on the page and another value when the radio buttons' checked properly is looked at with javascript, but I haven't yet found, so this question is no longer needed, but the associated demo discussed in the 1st answer may help someone wondering how to access radio button click status.***

**Original Question:**
When I press the browser history back button and return to a page that I just submitted, and which I'm developing, my code looks at the checked property state of a pair of radio-buttons to determine the mode that the page was in when it was last submitted and with this shows/hides page elements so that the page looks like it did when it was submitted. In the latest versions of Chrome and IE, Chrome works fine, but IE displays that the radio buttons appear to be checked differently than they look in the F12 Developer Tool Debugger, which shows the checked properties of these two radio buttons in the opposite state to what is seen on the page.

Is there a special way in IE to get a radio-button's value after using the back button?

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo page that shows that no special coding is needed to access the values of a input radio button element after pressing the browser's back button.  Here are two links to a CodePen that demonstrates this: 
[CodePen demo (debug mode)](https://cdpn.io/howardb1/debug/WNNzjNo/LDAmdEPmXXNr) or 
[CodePen demo (preview mode)](https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/WNNzjNo).

The demo only works properly in CodePen's debug mode, but you may want to see the normal CodePen preview/edit mode, so both links are provided.

Amongst all the ways to access the value of a input radio button's value, here are a few:

```
document.getElementById( 'radio_id' ).checked

document.getElementsByName( 'radio_name' ).checked              // deprecated in HTML5!

document.querySelector( 'input[name="radio_name"]' ).checked    // 1st radio button with the name.

document.querySelectorAll( 'input[name="radio_name"]' ).checked // all of the radio buttons
```